# A question about countably subadditive property of Lebesgue Outer Measure

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Here is the definition of Carothers' Lebesgue Outer Measure:

[image].

And countably subadditive property of Lebesgue Outer Measure has been talked here:

[image]

I can understand all proofs. However, I'm wondering why the set $G$ in Corollary 16.7 is necessarily open there? How about a closed set $G$? Similarly, see the proof following Corollary 16.7. Why should we necessarily find a sequence of open intervals ($I_n$)? How about a closed one or a neither open nor closed set?
Appreciate much.

Comment: @bof: So sorry. my typo, should be 16.7

Comment: In Corollary 16.7, suppose $E$ is the set of all rational numbers. There is no closed set $G$ containing $E$ such that $m^*(G)\le m^*(E)+1=1$; in fact, the only closed set containing $E$ is the set of all real numbers. So the best you can do is an open set.

Comment: @bof: coz an open set of $E$ works well for all subset $E$ of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @Frank_W: Also, I think that "infinite union of open sets is open" is used here, which is not true for closed set.

Comment: @RIchardWilliams: Yes. U r right. I've known.